# Ajax validation form directs the echo:s to antoher page then the one it should echo out on

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an ajax-form to validate the client side server of my sign up form.

I want the error messages to pop up in the same page as where they are written, meaning it shouldn't load another page.

Down below is my (signup.php)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("form").submit(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var first = $("#mail-first")val();
                    var last = $("#mail-last")val();
                    var email = $("#mail-email")val();
                    var uid = $("#mail-uid")val();
                    var pwd = $("#mail-pwd")val();
                    var submit = $("#mail-submit")val();
                    $(".form-message").load("includes/signup.inc.php", {
                        first: first,
                        last: last,
                        email: email,
                        uid: uid,
                        pwd: pwd,
                        submit: submit
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
  </head>
  <body id="signupbackground">

<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input id="mail-first"type="text" name="first" placeholder= "Firstname">
            <input id="mail-last" type="text" name="last" placeholder="Lastname">
            <input id="mail-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input id="mail-uid"type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="mail-pwd" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
            <p class="form-messsage"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

My (signup.inc.php) handles the php and the functions which is shown down below.
An example of the function code is

```
 `  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                echo "<span class='form-error'>Write a valid email!</span>";
                 $errorEmail = true;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email=?";`
```

The echo span is shown on another page then signup.php, why??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo to a page once it has loaded. You could try using _GET data to pass the error to the page then reload.

You would add this to your registration page:

```
<?php
$error = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'err', $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($error) {
    echo "<span class='form-error'> " . $error . "</span>";
}
?>
```

and this to your signup.inc.php:

```
header('Location: ../register.php?err=Write a valid email!');
```

or

```
header('Location: ../register.php?err=Username is already in use!');
```

etc